# How to upload a picture to cloudinary using ionic and cordova filetransfer?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, heroku, ionic-framework, ngcordova

i'm working on an ionic where i basically have a REST api with heroku that unables me to upload pictures and i'm trying to upload using cordova file transfer plugin and an HTTP post request 
i'm using ionicview to test my app on my phone 
and my api is hosted on heroku which can be found in this link https://peaceful-refuge-78844.herokuapp.com/ (static,upload   add one of the options after the slash) 
it returns as failed upload every time

**my controller :**

```
$scope.testConnection = function()
{
      $http.get('https://peaceful-refuge-78844.herokuapp.com/').then(function(result){
        $scope.serverConnection = "Connection OK";
    },
    function(err){
        $scope.serverConnection = "Connection fail";
    });

}
$scope.choosePhoto = function() {


    //Gallery
    var options = {
        quality: 80,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 500,
        targetHeight: 700,
        correctOrientation: true,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(photo){
        $rootScope.imgURI =  photo;
        $scope.lastPhoto = photo;



    })


       $scope.uploadPhoto = function()
{
   var options = new FileUploadOptions()
    options.fileKey = "image";
    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload('https://peaceful-refuge-78844.herokuapp.com//upload', $scope.lastPhoto, options).then(function(result) {
        console.log("File upload complete");
        console.log(result);
        $scope.url = result;
        $scope.uploadResults = "Upload completed successfully" 

    }, function(err) {
        console.log("File upload error");
        console.log(err);
        $scope.uploadResults = "Upload failed"                        
    }, function (progress) {
        // constant progress updates
        console.log(progress);
    });


}
```